# Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle for BB84 Protocol using Paulis Spin Matrices

Tags: pauli-gates, cryptography, bb84

I am doing a term project on the BB84 Protocol and it makes use of the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle. I think I understand the principle in theory. If we have two non-commuting observables, then we cannot simultaneously measure a state with these observables, since after the measurement the state collapses to one of the eigenstates of the observable, but non-commuting observables do not have common eigenstates. This is what I understood.

I also found that the Paulis spin matrices for x and z, which are used in the BB84 protocol do not commute. So they should (and no dot) have common eigenstates. I tried to find the Heisenberg inequality using the formula for the Heisenberg inequality where we use average values and each time for the 0 ket I find the inequality side 0. Shouldn't it give something other than 0?

Then I tried to justify the 0, thinking that maybe for one of the spin matrices the uncertainty is 0 since we are using the right operator, and that is why when we multiply the uncertainties we get 0?

Am I doing something wrong in my calculations, or have I completely misunderstood the subject.

Thanks for any kind of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Heisenberg principle is usually invoked to say that two operators don't commute and therefore if your qubit is in $|0\rangle$ which is an *eigenstate* of $\sigma_z$, you will have uncertainty in the measurement of $\sigma_x$. However, let's check that Heisenberg principle is still holding even in this situation!

Let's see Heisenberg's principle in this case. Heisenberg principle can be derived using **schwarz inequality**. Usually, some of the terms are omitted, but I will report the full principle. The Heisenberg principle for two operators $\hat A$ and $\hat B$ states that:

$$\langle\Delta^2A\rangle\langle \Delta^2B\rangle \geq \frac{1}{4}\left|\langle\{\hat A, \hat B\}\rangle - 2\langle \hat A \rangle \langle\hat B \rangle\right|^2 + \frac{1}{4}\left|\langle[\hat A, \hat B]\rangle\right|^2$$

You can read this stated in [1].

In our case we have $\hat A = \sigma_x$ and $\hat B = \sigma_y$. As you noticed if our state is in the $|0\rangle$ eigenstate o $\sigma_z$, then the expectation value $\langle\Delta^2A\rangle = 0$, hence the left hand side is 0!

However, for this particular state, also the right hand side is 0:

- $\{\sigma_z, \sigma_x\}=0$ (property of the Pauli matrices)
- $2\langle \sigma_z \rangle\langle \sigma_x \rangle = 0$ since $\langle \sigma_x \rangle = \langle 0 | \sigma_x | 0 \rangle = 0$ (you can check this one doing the matrix multiplication!)
- $\left|\langle[\sigma_z, \sigma_x]\rangle\right|^2 = 0$ because $[\sigma_z, \sigma_x]=-2i\sigma_y$ and the expectation value $\langle 0 | \sigma_y | 0 \rangle=0$.

Hence, the right hand side is 0 as well and heisenberg is saved (note that the inequality allows for the left and right to be equal)!

A last point is that $\sigma_z$, $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$ all have **different** eigenstates. However, they have the same eigen values $\pm 1$.

[1] https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.08705.pdf